# Spring RequestMapping URL with hierarchal values

Tags: java, spring

Lets say I have a `Category` domain model object that follows a file tree structure.  I want to be able to construct a `RequestMapping` annotation for the controller method so that

```
/category/art/macros
/category/people/weddings/2014/5-19
/category/sports/college/baseball/2014/5-19
```

can be handled by the minimum number of controller methods.

I already have one controller method defined:

```
@RequestMapping(value ={"/category/{category}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String adminCategory(ModelMap model, @PathVariable(value = "category") String category){
    model.addAttribute("message", category);
    return "gallery";
}
```

This works for a single URL like

```
/category/sports
```

How can I adapt this to be more flexible?

Answer (score 0):

The challenge is here that you can't make @PathVariable optional but you can have two or more controller methods which can call the same service code. So, for you three URL patterns you have to define three different controllers:

```
GET: /category/art/macros

@RequestMapping(value ={"/category/{category}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String adminCategory(ModelMap model, @PathVariable(value = "category") String category){
    model.addAttribute("message", category);
    return "gallery";
}


GET: /category/people/weddings/2014/5-19

@RequestMapping(value ={"/category/{category}/{subcategory}/{year}/{date}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String adminCategory(ModelMap model, @PathVariable(value = "category") String category,
    @PathVariable(value = "subcategory") String subcategory,
    @PathVariable(value = "year") String year,
    @PathVariable(value = "date") String date

){
    model.addAttribute("message", category, subcategory, year, date);
    return "gallery";
}

GET: /category/sports/college/baseball/2014/5-19

@RequestMapping(value ={"/category/{category}/{subcategory}/{year}/{date}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String adminCategory(ModelMap model, @PathVariable(value = "category") String category,
    @PathVariable(value = "subcategory") String subcategory,
    @PathVariable(value = "sub_sub_category") String sub_sub_category,
    @PathVariable(value = "year") String year,
    @PathVariable(value = "date") String date

){
    model.addAttribute("message", category, subcategory, sub_sub_category, year, date);
    return "gallery";
}
```

PS You can user @RequestParam which can be optional and reduce the number of controllers.

Comment: Correct, but this also reduces my flexibility when it comes to categories, as it mimics a tree structure.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this? What and where mimics tree structure?